# Why does Camel Servlet Mapping require a slash at the end of the url?

Tags: java, http, servlets, routes, apache-camel

I have a web application using camel routing and my question regards the servlet mapping in my web xml (see below). In general I have many different routes defined in my route builder which are accessed for example like this:

from("servlet://?matchOnUriPrefix=true&servletName=CamelRedirectErrorServlet")

and one "general" entry point which should catch everything else than these more specific routes:

from("servlet://?matchOnUriPrefix=true")

My problem is, that my servlets are accessible via this url:

http://my.url/redirect/back/?param1=value1&param2=value2

but this url leads to 404 not found:

http://my.url/redirect/back?param1=value1&param2=value2

To me it seems uncommon or even wrong to use all urls with the "/?" ending.
Can anyone help me out on this matter? I appreciate every idea.
Thank you in advance!! :-)

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CamelRedirectBackServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/redirect/back/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/redirect/back</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <!-- Camel redirect error servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CamelRedirectErrorServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!--  Camel redirect error servlet mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CamelRedirectErrorServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/redirect/error/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/redirect/error</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Camel servlet mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```